# Bone properties Tab does not get updated

Tags: bones, edit-mode, selection-tools

When I select a bone in Edit Mode, the Bone Properties tab does not get updated.
It shows always the details of a default bone. For example the bone I had selected last in Pose Mode, before switching back to Edit Mode.

I am using Blender 2.8 (Windows)

Is this a Bug, or did I something wrong (some strange settings)

Additionally, I cannot select a bone in Edit Mode by simply clicking on it (as it works in Pose Mode) I have to select it completely by the Circle Selector.

Can somebody help me out

Comment: I reverted already to Factory Properties and tried Linux version. No improvement

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 2.9. Realized I had accidentally hit <kbd>W</kbd> and switched to the circle select tool which made it so I could highlight new bones but the properties tab stayed on the originally selected bone.  Switched back to box select and then I could select as normal. Hope that helps

Comment: or hit w again to toggle off.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't Pin your Properties Editor:

[image]